# How can I force R markdown / LaTeX to display 'note' field in bibliography (display additional information)?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bibtex, bookdown

I use bibliography in my .Rmd file:

```
bibliography: bibliography.bib
```

My sample .bib entry looks as follows:

```
@misc{XYZ,
    author = "Somebody",
    note = "Accessed: 2017-01-10",
    title = "{Global database of LaTeX}",
    url = "http://writeInLatex.com",
    year = "2016"
}
```

I must display "notes" fields within the bibliography.
In case of the example above (web page) - information about access date, in case of the articles - language of the articles.

In case of the example above, I would like to have in the PDF file following entry:

> Somebody, 2016. Global database of LaTeX. Accessed: 2017-01-10

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you searched here? http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#citation_styles and the related links? You can search for your desired output with `note`.

Comment: So, if I wish to use https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/dependent/geoderma.csl style but add "note" field, I will need to download its parent style and modify parent? Is there any easier way? Could you provide me sample style with citations (one that I downloaded searching for the note seems to not working properly with my article).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I downloaded 'elsevier-harvard.csl' citation style from
   http://www.zotero.org/styles
2. I opened
   http://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/ and loaded mentioned
   style
3. Under bibliography layout I added node 'Text', set type:
   'variable' and selected variable 'note'
4. I changed name of the style
   and then downloaded it (elsevier-harvard-with-titles-with-notes.csl)
5. Within the header of my .Rmd file I added following
   line: `csl: elsevier-harvard-with-titles-with-notes.csl`

It works now!